What was the point of the Tecoma star?
It was briefly mentioned that the star

 Was boobytrapped

But by whom and why?


 It was manufactured and it was pointed at the ring gate. They aimed it like tying a shotgun trigger to a doorknob. Our bomb ship did something to activate it. ... It fired off the largest gun that it’s possible to make given the physical laws of the universe. And what’s more? The station was built to withstand it. It took a gamma burst from a collapsing neutron star, and it’s not dead. Tiamat's Wrath, Chapter Twenty-One

So it's likely built by the

Ring Builder,

against their enemy who was expected to go through the gate and do something similar to the

bombship.

